# How to enforce that only a given module in my app can change properties in my object?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class which has a State property. When instantiated, this property contains the current state of the object. The states have a well defined flow (example: from state 1 you can only go to states 2 and 3. From 2 you can only go to 4 and so on...), so I intent to create a module in my system that will manage these changes.
Ideally it would receive the object and the action performed and it would set the new state.
I am aware how to do that, but I am missing the point: how can I force everyone to use this module to change the state? I don't want anybody else changing the state, only this module.

Is there a design pattern or OO "trick" I could use?

I don't know if this is useful, but I am using JAVA EE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

out of the top of my head:

```
 class A {

   protected State state

   public State getState(){ return state; }
 }

 class B extends A {

   public void setState( State s ){ this.state = s }

 }
```

so the property remains read-only for all users of class A, but writable if you cast the instance to B.

UPDATE:

to use the callback-mechanismus:

```
 interface StateChanger(){ 
    public void call( State state );
 }

 class A {

   protected State state

   public State getState(){ return state; }

   public void setState( StateChanger stateChanger ){
     stateChanger.call( state );
   }
 }
```

then you can use it as:

```
 classAInstance.setState( new StateChanger(){
    @Override
    public void call( State state ){
      //do stuff
    }
 } );
```

Perhaps you need to include in the `StateChanger.call()` also the `this` as a parameter

in dynamic languages like Groovy it looks really compact

Comment: Sorry, I can't do this because my module in which I want to store all the knowledge about the state change is not conceptually a subclass. I did this because the flow is complex and I want to encapsulate it

Comment: You can also use an ( inner anonymous ) callback-class to set the new value of your `state` property. That would restrict the write-access to your property in 'political' way

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I have no idea how to do it, I will research about it, thanks for pointing me to this solution :)

Comment: added some lines into my original post

Comment: I will mark this one as answer because after a lot of reading and discussing with my team we understood that we were in the wrong direction: instead of the servicing updating the entity, the entity should call the service and update its own status. This answer was the thing that raised our discussion (btw: thanks! :) )

Answer (score 1):

You simply use package access visibility for your mutators/setters and put the instance to be secured in the same package with the classes in the module that can change it.

Example:

```
package com.bla.bla.bla.models;
public class ProtectedData {
    private String protectedField;
    public String getProtectedField() {
        return protectedField;
    }
    void setProtectedField(String newValue) {//package visibility
        this.protectedField = newValue;
    }
}

package com.bla.bla.bla.models;//the same package (no matter the name)
public class ProtectedWorkflowController {

    public void closeProtectedData(ProtectedData data) {
        data.setProtectedField(null);
    }
}
```

PS: the notion of module is `undefined` in Java, so I consider it is not wrong considering module==package in your case.

Comment: That sounds nice :). My class is currently on a com.bla.bla.bla.models package while my system is in another one. To make it work I would have to make both of them to be in the same package and be the only two classes in this package. Is this correct?

Comment: Exactly :) I added an example. You could have also multiple classes in that package, just make sure that no other classes in that module (I hope you control it and no one will have the bad idea to manipulate it from other classes of that package).

Comment: It looks nice, I will propose it to my team :)